# BeautifulSoup > prettify() method displays entire output in one line only

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.4

This is my first post on stackoverflow.com and I have a question w.r.t the output displayed in PyDev-for-Eclipse console for my Python3 program

I am using:
Python 3.4 ---
PyDev-for-Eclipse --- 
Python modules: requests, bs4, pprint

Whenever, I run the code below,

```
html_content = response.content
bs = BS(html_content,'html.parser')
page_html = bs.prettify(encoding='utf-8')
print(page_html)
```

The entire output is displayed in one line alone as shown below, instead of being displayed in a pretty print format

```
b'<!DOCTYPE doctype html>\n<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">\n <head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8"/> ...<entire output>...
```

I also tried with pprint() method from pprint module. However, I get the same result i.e. entire output displayed in one line alone

How do I get the o/p to be displayed in a preety print format?

Thanks,
skambl

Answer (score 2):

When you specify the `encoding` argument, you are asking it to encode the output.  This gives you a `bytes` object, which is recognizable by the leading `b` before the string that got printed.  `b'some value'` printed to the console means that you printed a `bytes` object (in python 3).

**Option 1**

```
print(page_html.decode('utf-8'))
```

Since you asked for it to be encoded as `utf-8`, that is what you should `decode` it as.

**Option 2**

Seems like you actually wanted a string (not a `bytes` object).  So just do

```
page_html = bs.prettify()  # no encoding parameter
```

Additionally, you may want to read the section on [Output formatters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) for more things you can do with the output.

I know you asked this a long time ago, but hopefully the answer is still helpful (particularly, knowing that the leading `b'...'` is a `bytes` object, and you need to `decode` that)!  I was searching for something related to bs4 and stumbled upon this, thought I would explain why you saw this behavior :)